# Add unique row identifiers to grouped long data

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following dataframe which I am trying to prepare for pivoting.

| Identifier | Data |
| --- | --- |
| X0001 | A |
| X0002 | B |
| X0002 | C |
| X0003 | G |
| X0004 | B |
| X0005 | B |
| X0005 | C |
| X0005 | D |

I'm trying to add a count for the number of times the same identifier has appeared as a 3rd column which I can then use as column headers to pivot the data.

| Identifier | Data | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X0001 | A | 1 |
| X0002 | B | 1 |
| X0002 | C | 2 |
| X0003 | G | 1 |
| X0004 | B | 1 |
| X0005 | B | 1 |
| X0005 | C | 2 |
| X0005 | D | 3 |

Final Pivoted Version

| Identifier | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X0001 | A |  |  |
| X0002 | B | C |  |
| X0003 | G |  |  |
| X0004 | B |  |  |
| X0005 | B | C | D |

would greatly appreciate if someone has any ideas on how I can add the Count column required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% group_by(Identifier) %>%
  mutate(d = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Identifier, names_from = d, values_from = Data)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Identifier [5]
  Identifier `1`   `2`   `3`  
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 X0001      A     NA    NA   
2 X0002      B     C     NA   
3 X0003      G     NA    NA   
4 X0004      B     NA    NA   
5 X0005      B     C     D
```